# Z3 code not running for specified number of iterations

Tags: python, z3

This code runs for only `i=4`, but if location is uninitialized, it runs for `i=19`?????
 `location=BoolVal(False)` location is initialized here

```
from z3 import *
x,t,t1,t2,x_next=Reals ('x t t1 t2 x_next')
location,location_next=Bools('location location_next')

x=20
#t1=0
t=0
location=BoolVal(False)
#set_option(precision=10)
k=20


for   i in range(k):
  s=Solver()

  s.add(Or(And((10*x_next)>=(3*t1)-(3*t2)+(10*x),(10*x_next)<=(10*x)-(t2-t1),x_next>=18,(t2-t1)>0,Not(location_next)),
           And((10*x_next)>=(t2-t1)+(10*x),(5*x_next)<=(5*x)+(t2-t1),x_next<=22,(t2-t1)>0,location_next)),
            location_next==If(And(Not(location),x_next<19),True,If(And(location,x_next>21),False,location)))


  print i
  print s.check()
  if s.check()==unsat:
      break

  m=s.model()
  x=m[x_next]
  #t1=m[t2]


  print m[x_next].as_decimal(10)
```

Comment: What/where is the `z3` module? I can't find it.

Comment: Also, your question is very unclear. Is the problem that you expect it to run for only `i=0...4`, but it actually runs from `i=0...19`? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: Its python code using Z3 API. Its the other way round. it is expected to run for i-----19.

Comment: Clearly the condition `if s.check()==unsat:` is True when `i == 4`, which leads it to `break`.

Comment: This is what i dont want to happen, and i couldnt find the solution.

Comment: You should clarify your question then. The problem isn't that it's "not running for the specified number of iterations," the problem is that z3 can't solve a certain equation.

Comment: if you see there are two sets of linear arithmetic constraints, representing two modes of a linear hybrid automata (on and off).Here we represent on by "True" and off by "False".The automaton starts in off mode with x=20. This mode reduces value of x and when x is less than 19 , the automaton should switch to on mode. This means it should satisfy the second set of constraints.In on mode x should increase and when it reaches where x>21, then it should switch to off again. This is how it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: the formula you add in the command `s.add(...)` is unsatisfiable at iteration 4.
At the beginning of iteration 4, we have that `x` is `19` and `location` is `False`.
By replacing `x` and `location` in the formula, we have that:

```
[Or(And(10*x_next >= 3*t1 - 3*t2 + 190,
        10*x_next <= 190 - t2 + t1,
        x_next >= 18,
        t2 - t1 > 0,
        Not(location_next)),
    And(10*x_next >= t2 - t1 + 190,
        5*x_next <= 95 + t2 - t1,
        x_next <= 22,
        t2 - t1 > 0,
        location_next)),
 location_next ==
 If(And(Not(False), x_next < 19),
    True,
    If(And(False, x_next > 21), False, False))]
```

After simplifying the formula above we have:

```
[Or(And(10*x_next >= 190 + 3*t1 - 3*t2,
           10*x_next <= 190 - t2 + t1,
           x_next >= 18,
           t2  - t1 > 0,
           Not(location_next)),
       And(10*x_next >= 190 + t2 - t1,
           5*x_next <= 95 + t2 - t1,
           x_next <= 22,
           t2 - t1 > 0,
           location_next)),
    location_next == x_next < 19]
```

To show the unsatisfiability of this formula, let us consider the following two cases: `location_next` is True, or `location_next` is False.

1. `location_next` is True. Then, `x_next < 19` must also be True. Moreover, the first argument of the `Or` is False. Thus, formula is satisfiable only if we can make the second argument True. This is not the case, since the following is unsatisfiable:

   `10*x_next >= 190 + t2 - t1,  5*x_next <= 95 + t2 - t1, x_next < 19`

   The first two inequalities imply that `x_next >= 19`.
2. `location_next` is False. Then `x_next >= 19` must be True. By a similar argument, the formula is satisfiable only if we can make the first argument of the `Or` True. This is also not possible, since the following is unsatisfiable:

   `10*x_next <= 190 - t2 + t1,  t2 - t1 > 0, 19 <= x_next`

   The first two inequalities imply that `x_next < 19`.

Remark: you did not update the value of `location` using `location_next` in the end of the loop. You do it for `x`, but not for `location`. This is an orthogonal problem. I was expecting a statement such as:

```
location=m[location_next]
```

Comment: this updating didnt make any difference. There seems to be some other issue i am not taking care off.

Comment: Can you give me a hint, what additional constraint i should have for this to be satisfiable?

Comment: location updating, i mean using this location=m[location_next] didnt make any difference.

Comment: As I said, the location updating is an orthogonal problem. It is not the source of the main problem.

Comment: Ok let me help in formulating this......The first argument of the Or should be satisfiable(If it really is satisfiable) if and only if location was False in the previous iteration,and location_next is False in the current iteration............Its the other way around for the second argument of Or.........how to add this constraint??

Comment: To me, the main problem is the fact you "set" the value of `location_next` in the two arguments of the `Or`, and in the equation with the `If`. I'm wondering if you meant `location` instead of `location_next` inside `Or`. Something like that: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/oRkqB

Comment: Let me tell you that this is a hybrid automata for thermostate to control room temperature.You might have noticed that there are abrupt changes in the values of x when mode off is False. I am skeptical about this.The temperature should increase and decrease smoothly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15019/discussion-between-hafizul-asad-and-leonardo-de-moura)